# R - How to graph percentages on a grouped bar graph?

Tags: r

I conducted a survey on who uses social media the most: males or females? Total is the # of people who do use it. The first number in the social media variables is for males, the second is for females.

```
 total <- c(24,21)
 facebook <- c(14,12)
 google_plus <- c(5,10)
 snapchat <- c(15,18)
 ifunny <- c(3,4)
 skype <- c(9,10)
 instagram <- c(21,18)
 ask_fm <- c(1,5)
 kik <- c(18,16)
 tumblr <- c(2,9)
 twitter <- c(10,12)
 fb_labels<-(facebook/total*100)
 fb_labels<-paste(fb_labels,"%")
 gplus_labels<-(google_plus/total*100)
 gplus_labels<-paste(gplus_labels,"%")
 snapchat_labels<-(snapchat/total*100)
 snapchat_labels<-paste(snapchat_labels,"%")
 ifunny_labels<-(ifunny/total*100)
 ifunny_labels<-paste(ifunny_labels,"%")
 skype_labels<-(skype/total*100)
 skype_labels<-paste(skype,"%")
 instagram_labels<-(instagram/total*100)
 instagram_labels<-paste(instagram_labels,"%")
 askfm_labels<-(ask_fm/total*100)
 askfm_labels<-paste(askfm_labels,"%")
 kik_labels<-(kik/total*100)
 kik_labels<-paste(kik_labels,"%")
 tumblr_labels<-(tumblr/total*100)
 tumblr_labels<-paste(tumblr_labels,"%")
 twitter_labels<-(twitter/total*100)
 twitter_labels<-paste(twitter_labels,"%")
```

My question is, how do I graph the percentages on a grouped bar graph? When I tried:

```
 dat <- cbind(fb_labels,gplus_labels)
 barplot(dat,beside=TRUE)
```

I got:

```
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thanks!

Comment: After executing your code I found that all 4 elements of `dat` were strings.  I suspect you didn't intend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pasted percent signs on `fb_labels` and `gplus_labels`, so they're now strings, not numbers. A reconstructed version with just the numbers works fine:

```
dat <- cbind(fb_labels = facebook/total*100, gplus_labels = google_plus/total*100)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add percents to the left side instead of plain numbers?

Comment: Where? You usually do it after the fact, say on your axis labels.